# Why does fstream::open() expect a C style string?

Tags: c++, fstream, c-strings

So I'm running this bit of sample code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  ifstream inFile;
  string str;

  cout << "\nEnter file name : ";
  cin >> str;

  try {
    inFile.open(str);
    if(!inFile)
      throw exception();
  } catch(exception e) {
    cout <<"\nAn exception was caught. file does not exist. ";
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And it gave me a compiler error :

```
test.cpp:14:13: error: no viable conversion from 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'const char *'
inFile.open(str);
            ^~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:517:24: note: passing argument to parameter '__s' here
      open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
```

I looked up the function prototype :

```
void open (const char* filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
void open (const string& filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

Why does fstream::open() expect a const String/ const char* ? The filename could be obtained from anywhere (from a user, like in the example above), and making `str` into a `const string` doesn't help in that case. 
I was able to get it to work by using `str.c_str()` instead, but could someone help me understand why the *const*-ness has been enforced in the file open method? Why shouldn't I be allowed to use a string as is, without having to use a char* or convert it into a c-style string?

Comment: IIRC Stroustrup talks about the fact that the streams library and `std::string` were designed in parallel.

Comment: Its because you are using an old C++03 compiler. This only allowed `open(char const*)`. The new C++11 compiler added the `open(std::string const&)` method. This will take both normal and const strings (the const indicator is a promise by the function it will not modify the string and adding constness is not an issue). Try compiling your code with `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: hmm, just tried `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp `  and `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp` - both of them still give me the same compiler error..I've got Xcode5, so this should work, apparently :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the syntax for the function signatures:

> Why does fstream::open() expect a const String/ const char* ? The
>   filename could be obtained from anywhere (from a user, like in the
>   example above), and making str into a const string doesn't help in
>   that case.

The signatures are below for reference:

```
void open (const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
void open (const string& filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

The first overload takes a `const char*` (e.g. a pointer to a constant character array).
The second overload takes a `const std::string&` (e.g. a reference to a constant std::string).

It is not a `const std::string`, but a **reference** to a string.  It is stating that the function will not modify the string, and you are passing a reference to the original (instead of copying it).  You can pass a non-const string to a function that requires a const string without an issue (there is no conversion/cast required).

The answer to your original question (Why does it take a `const char*`?) is not all that complicated:  The stream libraries and the string libraries were developed in parallel by different groups of people.  In the early standards, they didn't merge the development.  That has been addressed in C++11.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a non-`const` object to a function that takes a `const` reference.

The problem is that you don't have (or haven't enabled) C++11 support, so the `string` overload is missing. If you're stuck with a pre-2011 library, then your only option is to use `c_str()` to get a C-style string pointer.

Answer (score 3):

C++11's (enabled with `-std=c++0x` or `std=c++11`  flag )

```
void open (const string& filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

won't cause any issue with non-const string object.

The `const string &` helps to avoid unnecessary copying of string object

Comment: Mentioned this above as well - tried `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` and `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp` - both of them still give me the same compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `open` takes a `const char*` doesn't mean you can't pass it a regular `char*`. `char*` can be converted to `const char*`, just not the other way around (unless you  use `const_cast`, but those are evil).

This declaration is just saying "`open` takes a character string as input, and it promises not to modify the contents".

Answer (score 2):

you code compiles fine with the current standard (C++11), which sadly is not used by default by any compiler I know of.